# Cannot list projectsV2 with GitHub Cli due to missing scopes

Tags: graphql, github-cli

When running a GraphQL query with the GitHub CLI that uses the [projectsV2](https://docs.github.com/en/graphql/reference/objects#projectv2connection), I get an error complaining about missing scopes:

`Your token has not been granted the required scopes to execute this query. The 'projectsV2' field requires one of the following scopes: ['read:project'], but your token has only been granted the: ['admin:public_key', 'gist', 'read:org', 'repo'] scopes. Please modify your token's scopes at: https://github.com/settings/tokens.`

Sample Query:

```bash
> gh api graphql -f query='{
  organization(login: "MyOrg") {
    projectsV2(last: 20) {
      nodes {
        title
      }
    }
  }
}'
```

How can I elevate the permissions of GitHub's CLI?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default, GitHub's CLI only requests a few scopes when authenticating via `gh auth login`. However, the new projectsV2 requires `read:project` as well.

This can be solved by requesting an additional scope during login, like so:

```bash
> gh auth login --scopes read:project
```

Or, if you also need to write to projects, you might even need full access to projects, like so:

```bash
> gh auth login --scopes project
```

*Note that you might need to logout first: `gh auth logout`*

Comment: You can use refresh to add a scope. `gh auth refresh -h github.com -s admin:public_key`